# How to replace a specific value in all columns with a value that is the result of a function including the respective column for a big dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, apply

I have a very big dataframe filled with integers from `1` to `4`. For this dataframe, I want to replace all `1`s with the median of the respective column where the median is computed by excluding the integer I want to replace (so `1`).

Here is the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(rep(c(1,2,3,4), 10000000)), nrow = 500))
```

I know this works:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  
  df[,i][df[,i] == 1] <- median(df[,i][df[,i] != 1])
  print(i) # this is just to show how fast the loop is
  
}
```

And I know this works:

```
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), 
                       ~case_when(. == 1 ~ median(.[. != 1]),
                                  TRUE ~ .)))
```

However, both approaches are too slow for my real dataset comprising of 570.000 columns. I am sure there is a faster way to do this operation for every column of a big dataframe. I looked into the `*apply` family but didn't see a verb that takes a `data.frame` as an input and yields a `data.frame` as an output.

Possible other functions I found but couldn't bring to work are: `aggregate` and `by`.

So my question: Is there a faster way to do this other than the two approaches I showed above, specifically for big dataframes with many columns?

Comment: There is probably not a lot you can do to reduce the time it needs to perform this operation across all 570k columns (that is a massive dataframe). If I understand your problem, you can save the first loop. Apparently you are replacing every 1 in a column by the median of the column excluding the 1. Thus, it is sufficient, if you calculate this once, i.e. remove one 1 from the column/vector and take the median.  You can then replace (all) the 1's with the median.

Comment: Can you clarify for me what you mean by: "you can save the first loop."?

Comment: If you have a column with n-times the value 1, you calculate the median of this column. It was not clear whether you calculate the median with the other 1s also replaced. But even in the case of using n-1-times the (other 1s) and the rest of the column is an identical operation for all 1s in that column. Thus, you can calculate the median for the column without looping over every row.  (In principle you replicate the median calculation per row  - and given your data, you could simplify this by calculating it for the cases in your data. This avoids looping over all rows.

Comment: This also holds for your other values. You calculate the median over your column vector for an instance of 1, 2, 3, or 4. In case of 1, you replace the 1's ... possibly also for the other instances. But the median will not change. Thus, you calculate for the instances, i.e. 4 cases. This saves you from iterating over each row. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Let's say I have a small example column. As a vector, this column looks like this `c(1,1,2,3,4)`. What I want to do is i want to exclude the value `1` so my new vector looks like this `c(2,3,4)`. From this vector I calculate now the median. This median then is used to replace all the `1`s from the original vector (i.e. the original column). So the result would look like this `c(3,3,2,3,4)`. And I want to repeat this operation for all columns of my big dataframe. I hope this carifies it.